# How to change the name of a WSL distro to reflect the actual distro?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-18.04

I have WSL 2 installed on my Windows 10 machine. I switched over to version 1 and upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 19.04 using the do-release-upgrade command. I then tried to switch over to WSL 2, but I noticed the output of `wsl -l -v` is Ubuntu 18.04, not 19.04, but when running an Ubuntu prompt the output of `lsb_release -a` is accurately 19.04. I then tried moving the distro as named over to WSL 2 anyway, and received a

```
Exporting the distribution failed.
bsdtar: Write error
```

error. I am hoping that updating the name to the actual distro (19.04) will solve this issue. Any idea on how to do that? Probably it's in some config file for WSL?

Comment: Does that distribution works now as WSL2?

Comment: Including the exact commands used when moving the distro would help diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 26):

If you want to rename your WSL distro, you have to:

1. Stop all instances of WSL
2. Open Registry Editor and go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss`
3. Find the distro you want to rename, look for the `DistributionName`
4. Change it as you want
5. Start WSL again, you can also execute `wsl.exe -l -v` to check if it changes

Comment: Now how do we get vscode to stop throwing errors do to an outdated reference somewhere? I'm getting errors that include the following, which refers to the old distro name, not the newer 20.04 one. `ENOPRO: No file system provider found for resource 'vscode-remote://wsl%2Bubuntu18.04/home/...`

Comment: And how to update the original App shortcut: `WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80070050 The file exists.`. Its Properties/Target is inactive. This answer is either incomplete or even potentially harmful.

Comment: @rainabba Restarting the `LxssManager` service has solved this. Thanks to the other answer for mentioning it.

Comment: This *still* worked for me, even with the latest WSL 2 (that includes WSLg). I kind of thought it wouldn't.

Answer (score 10):

`(1):` Open the Windows registry editor (`regedit`), and paste the following `URI` in its adddress bar:

`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss`

`(2):` In the left-side navigation pane, examine folders that look like this `{xxxxxxxx-yyyy-xxxx-yyyy-xxxxxxxxxxxx}`. (The folder name contains all Hexadecimal digits). Double-click each one until you find the wsl distribution with the name you want to change.

`(3):` In the right-side navigation pane, double-click the `REG_SZ` item called `DistributionName`, and edit its content to whatever you want. Save it.

`(4):` Finally, restart `wsl`.

- Press: `Win + R` on your PC.
- Type `services.msc` into the search box that pops up.
- In Services Manager tool that pops up, find the first `LxssManager` entry in the list, and restart it.

That should do it.

`NOTE`: Do not skip step `(4)`, because doing so will cause some `wsl` applications launch with errors. For example, `Visual Studio Code` will not launch correctly because `wsl` has not been refreshed / restarted.

PS: Don't forget to edit the launch property of your application launch icons. Any of them specifying the `-d distroName` option to `wsl.exe [...]` or `wslg.exe [...]` will need to be edited.

Answer (score 4):

Just ran into this myself. Though it's basically just cosmetic and only comes up when running WSL specific commands, I wanted to keep things from getting confusing in the future.

What I ended up using [LxRunOffline](https://github.com/DDoSolitary/LxRunOffline) to duplicate my Distro, which in the process allows you to name the duplicate, setting the duplicate as default, and then uninstalling my old Distro.

Example of what I did(ran in powershell from my user's home directory):

```
#List installed Distros
LxRunOffline.exe l
#Duplicate Ubuntu-18.04 to folder in my user directory and name it Ubuntu
LxRunOffline.exe d -n Ubuntu-18.04 -d ./WSL/Ubuntu -N Ubuntu
#Set new Distro as default
LxRunOffline.exe sd -n Ubuntu
#Uninstall old Distro
LxRunOffline.exe ui -n Ubuntu-18.04
```

PS: To be clear, the WSL listed name of your Distro is unrelated to what is really running inside the Distro. So you just have to use the current name WSL currently lists, in the WSL2 convert command.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The reason I prefer it over the other two answers, is that this is the only answer that copies the *whole distro*.
The other two answers describe how to *change the name in the registry*.
By this method, I can have *both* openSUSE-42 *and* openSUSE-15.
If I just rename openSUSE-42 to openSUSE-15, then I will get an error if I try to reinstall
with `wsl.exe --install --distribution openSUSE-42`.
No error with this method! Thanks.